# Widgets for backpack Laravel with data base

Tags: phpmyadmin, widget, laravel-backpack

i'am using backpack for laravel.I want to put in my home page some widgets but i don't know how to put it dynamically with database

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the section in the docs called [Creating a custom widget type](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/base-widgets#creating-a-custom-widget-type) - it explains that there are 3 ways you can do this:

- use the full namespace for your models, like `\App\Models\Product::count()`;
- load all your dashboard information using AJAX calls, if you're loading charts, reports, etc, and the DB queries might take a long time;
- use view composers to push variables inside this view when it's loaded, Like. `View::composer('backpack::widgets.well, 'App\Http\View\Composers\WellComposer');` you'll find more information about this in the [Laravel docs about view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers)

Personally I'd recommend the third option.